# Salesforce Page auto update upon update of database

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have the following page that shows documents from database, what  I'm trying to accomplish is to make this page refresh or update automatically if a new document is added in the database. Is there a way I can use AJAX or pulling or something in my controller or page to accomplish that ?

Page:

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!docs}" var="d" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(docs))}" Title="Documents">  
        <apex:column headerValue="Name">
               <apex:outputText value="{!d.Name}"/>           
       </apex:column>   
   </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Contoller

```
 public List<FTPAttachment__c> getDocs()
    {
        docs= [Select Name from FTPAttachment__c where Case__c  = :cse.id];
        return docs;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the `<apex:actionPoller>` tag:

```
<apex:actionPoller action="{!refreshDocs}" rerender="docsTable" interval="5" />
<apex:pageBlockTable id="docsTable" value="{!docs}" var="d" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(docs))}" Title="Documents">  
    <apex:column headerValue="Name">
        <apex:outputText value="{!d.Name}"/>           
    </apex:column>   
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

You could have the `refreshDocs()` method explicitly repopulate the `docs` list, but since you're already doing that in your getter (which will be called when the table is re-rendered), this method can just return without doing anything special:

```
public List<FTPAttachment__c> getDocs() {
    return [Select Name from FTPAttachment__c where Case__c  = :cse.id];
}
public PageReference refreshDocs() {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use the streaming api.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_streaming/index.htm

Comment: The Streaming API seems like it would be useful for this, but because of the overly restrictive limits (10 clients per channel max) it is really only suitable for server-to-server communication.